# How to get data of the most current date in the table, and the 7 days prior to that

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following code:

```
df_curr = pd.read_sql_query('select  * from vr.ultrasound where DATEDIFF(day, eventdate, CAST( GETDATE() as date)) <=1', conn)

df_old = pd.read_sql_query('select  * from vr.ultrasound where (DATEDIFF(day, eventdate, CAST( GETDATE() as date)) <=8 and DATEDIFF(day, eventdate, CAST( GETDATE() as date))>=2) ', conn)
```

but this is using current system date in df_curr whereas I want the date to be the final / max date in the table which is not necessarily the same as GETDATE(). The same problem affects df_old as well.

Update:

For df_old, I am now using:

```
select  * from vr.ultrasound where

eventdate < (SELECT MAX(eventdate) FROM vr.ultrasound)
 
and 

DATEDIFF(day, eventdate, MAX(eventdate) FROM vr.ultrasound) <=8
```

but am faced with the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Comment: use this `(SELECT MAX(eventdate) FROM vr.ultrasound)` code instead of `getdate()`

Comment: this will be for df_curr, yes. but how to get data for df_old (the 7 days prior to MAX(eventdate)?)

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help. If you have a single row per day you can just do `SELECT TOP (8) ... ORDER BY eventdate DESC`

Comment: I have updated the question to show my new attempt

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer by experimenting!

-- For df_curr

```
select  * from vr.ultrasound where
eventdate = (SELECT MAX(eventdate) FROM vr.ultrasound)
```

-- For df_old

```
select  * from vr.ultrasound where (


eventdate < (SELECT MAX(eventdate) FROM vr.ultrasound) 

 and 

eventdate > DATEADD (day,-7,(SELECT MAX(eventdate) FROM vr.ultrasound)) )

order by eventdate desc
```